# Spring amqp's RabbitConnectionFactoryBean cannot connect over TLS to inbound while it works to outbound

Tags: ssl, rabbitmq, spring-integration, spring-amqp

I am struggling with my attemps to establish an AMQP over TLS connection within a messaging brigde.

The odd thing is that it works perfectly well when I perform an outbound connection... but fails with a "*{unsupported_record_type,65}*" error (from *rabbitmq.log*) for an inbound connection .

It looks like I am trying to connect the NON-SSL way on a SSL port.

I can see the listeners for AMQPS is up from diagnostics:

```
rabbitmq-diagnostics listeners
Asking node rabbit@host to report its protocol listeners ...
...
Interface: 127.0.0.1, port: 5672, protocol: amqp, purpose: AMQP 0-9-1 and AMQP 1.0
Interface: 10.1.2.3, port: 5672, protocol: amqp, purpose: AMQP 0-9-1 and AMQP 1.0
Interface: 10.1.2.3, port: 5671, protocol: amqp/ssl, purpose: AMQP 0-9-1 and AMQP 1.0 over TLS
```

I also checked configuration to see if my TLS version was ok:

```
ssl_options.versions.1 = tlsv1.3
ssl_options.versions.2 = tlsv1.2
```

When I try to look through *tcpdump*, I do not see 'AMQP' footprints, but TCP (SYN,ACK,PSH) followed by the TLSv1.2 attempt with the above error ("Unexpected Message")

I also tried to do both publishing and consuming using [perftest](https://rabbitmq.github.io/rabbitmq-perf-test/stable/htmlsingle/) , using the same key/truststore, and it works very well.

All these clues make me think it's related to my *inbound-adapter* and the way I configure it... but I can't see the (obvious?) mistake so far.

My libs/xsd versions are:

- spring-integration-amqp-5.2.xsd
- spring-integration-5.2.xsd
- spring-rabbit.xsd
- spring-integration-amqp : 6.0.4
- spring-integration-core : 6.0.4

Here are both the working outbound connection and the failing inbound one :

```
<!-- INBOUND FAILING ADAPTER --> 
<bean id="connectionAmqpFactorySrc" class="com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory">
    <property name="automaticRecoveryEnabled" value="true"/>
    <property name="networkRecoveryInterval" value="10000"/>
</bean>


<bean id="listeners" class="java.util.ArrayList">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <ref bean="connectionAmqpListener" /> <!-- for logging purpose -->
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
        
<bean id="clientSSLConnectionFactory" 
   class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.RabbitConnectionFactoryBean" 
   factory-bean="connectionAmqpFactorySrc">
    <property name="useSSL" value="true"/>
    <property name="keyStore" value="./keycert.p12" />
    <property name="keyStorePassphrase" value="*****"  />
    <property name="keyStoreType" value="PKCS12" />
    <property name="trustStore" value="./trustsore.jks" />
    <property name="trustStorePassphrase" value="****"  />
    <property name="trustStoreType" value="JKS" />
    <property name="sslAlgorithm" value="TLSv1.2" />
    <property name="saslConfig" value="#{T(com.rabbitmq.client.DefaultSaslConfig).PLAIN}"/> 
    <property name="enableHostnameVerification" value="true"/>
 </bean>


<bean id="rabbitConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
    <constructor-arg value="clientSSLConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="username" value="user" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />
    <property name="addresses" value="some.full.qualified.name:5671" />
    <property name="cacheMode" value="CONNECTION" />
    <property name="connectionCacheSize" value="50" />
    <property name="virtualHost" value="/" />
    <property name="connectionListeners" ref="listeners" />
</bean>

<bean id="fixedBackOffRabbitMQ" class="org.springframework.util.backoff.FixedBackOff">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="8000" />
    <constructor-arg index="1" value="2" />
</bean>
    
<bean id="myListener" class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="rabbitConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="queueNames" value="some.queue.in" />
    <property name="recoveryBackOff" ref="fixedBackOffRabbitMQ"/>
    <property name="channelTransacted" value="true"></property>
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="2"></property>
    <property name="prefetchCount" value="1"></property>
    <property name="errorHandler" ref="errorHandler"></property>
    
</bean>
    
<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter   channel="channelRmqs2Stg" 
                                    id="inboundChannelAdapter" 
                                    auto-startup="true" listener-container="myListener" error-channel="processChannelError" />






<!-- OUTBOUND WORKING ADAPTER --> 
<bean id="connectionAmqpFactoryDst" class="com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory"  >
    <property name="networkRecoveryInterval" value="10000"/>
    <property name="automaticRecoveryEnabled" value="true"/>
</bean>

<bean id="clientSSLConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.RabbitConnectionFactoryBean"  factory-bean="connectionAmqpFactoryDst">
    <property name="useSSL" value="true"/>
    <property name="keyStore" value="./keycert.p12" />
    <property name="keyStorePassphrase" value="*****"  />
    <property name="keyStoreType" value="PKCS12" />
    <property name="trustStore" value="./trustsore.jks" />
    <property name="trustStorePassphrase" value="****"  />
    <property name="trustStoreType" value="JKS" />
    <property name="sslAlgorithm" value="TLSv1.2" />
    <property name="saslConfig" value="#{T(com.rabbitmq.client.DefaultSaslConfig).PLAIN}"/> 
    <property name="enableHostnameVerification" value="true"/>
 </bean>

<rabbit:connection-factory id="rabbitConnectionFactory" 
        connection-factory="clientSSLConnectionFactory"
        addresses="some.full.qualified.name:5671"
        username="user"
        password="password" 
        cache-mode="CONNECTION" 
        connection-cache-size="50" 
        virtual-host="/" 
        connection-limit="1"/>

<rabbit:template    id="rabbitTemplate"  
                    connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory"  
                    mandatory="true" 
                    channel-transacted="true"/>

<int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter  channel="channelStg2Rmqs" 
                                    routing-key="some.queue.out" 
                                    exchange-name="amq.direct" 
                                    amqp-template="rabbitTemplate" 
                                    default-delivery-mode="PERSISTENT"/>
```

Any idea?